# Sql Join Query Issue

Tags: php, sql

I've a mysql table called `tutor_signup_form` is look like this

```
id    feerange    gender    name
1     20          male      alex      
2     10          female    Robin
3     15          male      Babu
```

Now I've a html search form where few drop down selected fields and many Chckbox fields are exist. I want to get the search result from multiple table using sql `INNER JOIN`. My `INNER JOIN` query is look like this

```
// search query
$query =  mysql_query("SELECT tutor_signup_form . *, tutor_signup_edu_psle . *,
tutor_signup_edu_olevel . *, tutor_signup_edu_alevel . *, tutor_signup_edu_diploma . *,
tutor_signup_edu_degree . *, tutor_signup_edu_masters . *, tutor_signup_edu_psd . *,
tutor_signup_level_primary . *, tutor_signup_level_olevel . *, tutor_signup_level_alevel . *,
tutor_signup_level_int . *, tutor_signup_level_uni . *, tutor_signup_level_music . *,
tutor_signup_level_lang . *, tutor_signup_level_com . *, tutor_signup_pre_central . *,
tutor_signup_pre_east . *, tutor_signup_pre_west . *, tutor_signup_pre_south . *,
tutor_signup_pre_north . *, tutor_signup_pre_ne . *, tutor_signup_pre_nw . *  FROM tutor_signup_form

INNER JOIN tutor_signup_edu_psle ON tutor_signup_form.tutor_id = tutor_signup_form.tutor_id     
INNER JOIN tutor_signup_edu_olevel ON tutor_signup_form.tutor_id = tutor_signup_edu_olevel.tutor_id
INNER JOIN tutor_signup_edu_alevel ON tutor_signup_form.tutor_id = tutor_signup_edu_alevel.tutor_id 
INNER JOIN tutor_signup_edu_diploma ON tutor_signup_form.tutor_id = tutor_signup_edu_diploma.tutor_id
INNER JOIN tutor_signup_edu_degree ON tutor_signup_form.tutor_id = tutor_signup_edu_degree.tutor_id
INNER JOIN tutor_signup_edu_masters ON tutor_signup_form.tutor_id = tutor_signup_edu_masters.tutor_id
INNER JOIN tutor_signup_edu_psd ON tutor_signup_form.tutor_id = tutor_signup_edu_psd.tutor_id
INNER JOIN tutor_signup_level_primary ON tutor_signup_form.tutor_id = tutor_signup_level_primary.tutor_id
INNER JOIN tutor_signup_level_olevel ON tutor_signup_form.tutor_id = tutor_signup_level_olevel.tutor_id
INNER JOIN tutor_signup_level_alevel ON tutor_signup_form.tutor_id = tutor_signup_level_alevel.tutor_id
INNER JOIN tutor_signup_level_int ON tutor_signup_form.tutor_id = tutor_signup_level_int.tutor_id
INNER JOIN tutor_signup_level_uni ON tutor_signup_form.tutor_id =  tutor_signup_level_uni.tutor_id
INNER JOIN tutor_signup_level_music ON tutor_signup_form.tutor_id = tutor_signup_level_music.tutor_id
INNER JOIN tutor_signup_level_lang ON tutor_signup_form.tutor_id = tutor_signup_level_lang.tutor_id
INNER JOIN tutor_signup_level_com ON tutor_signup_form.tutor_id =  tutor_signup_level_com.tutor_id
INNER JOIN tutor_signup_pre_central ON tutor_signup_form.tutor_id = tutor_signup_pre_central.tutor_id
INNER JOIN tutor_signup_pre_east ON tutor_signup_form.tutor_id = tutor_signup_pre_east.tutor_id
INNER JOIN tutor_signup_pre_west ON tutor_signup_form.tutor_id = tutor_signup_pre_west.tutor_id
INNER JOIN tutor_signup_pre_south ON tutor_signup_form.tutor_id = tutor_signup_pre_south.tutor_id
INNER JOIN tutor_signup_pre_north ON tutor_signup_form.tutor_id =  tutor_signup_pre_north.tutor_id
INNER JOIN tutor_signup_pre_ne ON tutor_signup_form.tutor_id = tutor_signup_pre_ne.tutor_id
INNER JOIN tutor_signup_pre_nw ON tutor_signup_form.tutor_id = tutor_signup_pre_nw.tutor_id 

WHERE tutor_signup_form.feerange <= '$budget'");
```

For example I selected budget field = 20. So my query should be product only 3 results from `tutor_signup_form` but it's produce 24 results. I don't understand why it's produce 24 result. Can you fix it ?

Update:

[image]

Comment: On a (very important) aside; you really should read up on database normalization ...

Comment: @Sherlock in this case I think it's the main matter not 'aside' :)

Comment: The biggest `INNER JOIN` I've even seen. You should offer a bounty for this ;)

Comment: Well, I'll try to help you... first of all, delete your second and third join since they are duplicated - you're using them twice and check the results.

Comment: @hex494D49 Ok I'm doing this.

Comment: @hex494D49 No, I think there is no twice join query.

Comment: I see, different table names. Is it possible to make a screenshot of your database schema or maybe to put a small dump od data here http://sqlfiddle.com/ 'casue I can't see why you have to use all the tables above.

Comment: @hex494D49 I'm doing both.

Comment: @hex494D49 I updated the question. Check the picture.

Comment: Cool, but that screenshot will not help us ;) since I can't see the structure. Since you're using phpMyAdmin, go to `Export tab`, and make a dump with only a few lines of data. Use `Maximal length of created query` option to limit records and then paste it http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: @hex494D49 I got the solution. it was wrong statement In my first Inner Join query.

Comment: I see, I missed that line... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Deadman mentioned, Cartesian...

Your first inner join was a copy/paste of table names

```
INNER JOIN tutor_signup_edu_psle 
   ON tutor_signup_form.tutor_id = tutor_signup_form.tutor_id
```

should have been

```
INNER JOIN tutor_signup_edu_psle 
   ON tutor_signup_form.tutor_id = tutor_signup_edu_psle.tutor_id
```

I have not read past that, but will in the mean-time

In addition, you have all your joins as INNER JOINs.  If someone does not have a record in one of the tables (such as Music), but does tutoring in Computers, and someone searches for Computers, they will not be returned.  I suggest changing to LEFT JOIN for all of them, so if the record exists in the tutoring subsidiary level, you are good and won't loose it.

Comment: Oh! Awesome. I was blind!. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Shibbir, see revised answer regarding left vs inner join.

Comment: Another great suggestion. You are Rock. I need to learn php and mysql in depth.

Comment: @Shibbir, it's not just PHP, but querying in general.   The syntax between engines may be slightly different, but the principles are the same across them all, especially getting into inner, left, right, outer joins.  Also, a suggestion, use aliases on table names to keep your queries shorter and more readable...

Answer (score 0):

If I've got it right you need to check your where clause.i think Cartesian product of the tables involved in the join.
The size of a Cartesian product result set is the number of rows in the first table multiplied by the number of rows in the second table